# Qthread с продолжением

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread

Хочу сделать контроллер потоков, который будет один и тот же объект `Worker` несколько раз запускать. Как это сделать?

Ниже будет пример, который вызывает функцию `Worker::process`, только один раз, хотя я 2 раза вызываю функцию `thr->start()`.

## Пример

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    int i = 0;
public:
    Worker() : QObject() { }
signals:
    void finished(int i);
public slots:
    void process();
};

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Worker *w;
    QThread *thr;
public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
private slots:
    void middleFinish(int i);
public slots:
    void start();
signals:
    void finished(int i);
};

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Controller _c;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

void Worker::process() { finished(++i); }

void Controller::start() {
    thr = new QThread;
    w = new Worker;
    w->moveToThread(thr);
    connect(thr, &QThread::started, w, &Worker::process);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, this, &Controller::middleFinish);
    thr->start();
}
void Controller::middleFinish(int i) {
    qDebug() << "middleFinish" << i;
    disconnect(w, &Worker::finished, this, &Controller::middleFinish);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, this, &Controller::finished);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, thr, &QThread::quit);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, w, &Worker::deleteLater);
    connect(thr, &QThread::finished, thr, &QThread::deleteLater);
    thr->start();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&_c, &Controller::finished, this, [] (int i) { qDebug() << "finish" << i; });
    _c.start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

Comment: `Хочу сделать контроллер потоков, который будет один и тот же объект Worker несколько раз запускать.` Но в примере почему-то пытаетесь запустить два раза поток, а не воркер, при этом когда вы второй раз запускаете поток, он, возможно, ещё не завершился. А если даже завершился, то вряд-ли запустится второй раз

Comment: ну так что делать? создавать новый поток, кидать туда объект и запускать?

Comment: Вообще, есть [qtconcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html). Там есть `QRunnable` и пул потоков. Если очень надо делать свою реализацию, то делаете класс `Worker`, который бесконечно крутится в этом потоке (можно по таймеру его запускать раз в n ms), и на каждой итерации этот воркер должен вытаскивать очередную задачу из очереди задач, выполнять её, а результат класть в очередь результатов. Вам понадобится взять где-то ThreadSafeQueue, и написать абстракции для задач и их выполнения, а также для результатов задач

Comment: Просто каждый раз запускать поток чтобы выполнить задачу - это расточительство. Проще держать несколько дополнительных потоков (хотя бы один), и иметь возможность давать этому потоку задачи на выполнение. Когда задач много. А если задача одна, и редко появляется (по кнопке), тогда да - можно действительно запустить поток, выполнить задачу, завершить поток, и забыть.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понимаю, чего Вы хотите добиться, но если хотите использовать связку thread-worker, при этом поток у Вас будет один, а вот worker будет отрабатывать N раз тогда и стартуйте Ваш worker N раз. Для этого Вам необходимо либо привязать сигнал к слоту `Worker::process` и испускать этот сигнал тогда, когда нужно. Либо использовать напрямую `QMetaObject::invoke`, как-то так:

```
void Controller::runProcessing()
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(w, "process");
}
```

Теперь вызывайте этот метод, когда хотите запустить обработку на worker.

У Вас же в коде Вы зачем-то запускаете один и тот же поток 2 раза (`thr->start()`), но это так не работает. Поток запускается один раз, а не 2.